# karate jsonObject[*].label and $jsonObject[*].label throws an error

Tags: karate

jsonObject :

```
[
   {
    "label": "Happy",
    "key": "478870b9-2d6012",
    "version": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "Face",
    "key": "478870b9-2d60698",
    "version": 3
  }
]
```

When i perform  `jsonObject[*].label` and `$jsonObject[*].label` throws an error,
Can someone please help!

I am expecting ["Happy","Face"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
* def jsonObject = 
"""
[
   {
    "label": "Happy",
    "key": "478870b9-2d6012",
    "version": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "Face",
    "key": "478870b9-2d60698",
    "version": 3
  }
]
"""
* def temp = $jsonObject[*].label
* match temp == ['Happy', 'Face']
```

Comment: As i am calling to an external function to get data, what all types of datatype are supported in this pattern? My obj type is list   when is use * print karate.typeOf(jsonObject)

Comment: Come on Peter, i knew karate is awesome.
Looks like issue is when you do a direct print it fails, i need to store in a variable and print

Comment: @SandeepP I have no idea what that is about - but read this also: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion